# build form with several ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, synchronous

Im trying to build a form with 2 ajax calls. in the first call i get some information about a ranking that i put on the form like this:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: base_url + "/ranking/getranktoedit/" + rank_id,
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(response){
    // grab the response and complete some html and then bind the javascript to handle clicks on this new generated piece of HTML
});
```

Inside the "done" part, i have to make another ajax call to get another bit of the HTML. I can make it work by using the "async:false" in the second ajax call, but i read that this is deprecated. So the question is simple, hoy do i make the second basically stop the whole process so i get the data on the page instead of the "undefined"?
I was also checking the option of using `$.when()` that seems a bit easier, but then i realise i didn't know how to basically force the async into sync... does that makes sense?
I'm not sure if I'm being clear, so please let me know if you need more details and I'll add any other information required. Thanks!

***UPDATE***
the piece of javascript looks something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: base_url + "/ranking/getranktoedit/" + rank_id,
    dataType: "json",
    sucess: function(response){
        let select_options;
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url: base_url + "/getdropdown",
            data: {
                field:"name"
            },
            success: function(name_dd){
                // this part is a bit more complex but it's just about putting things in the right place, nothing else
                return select_options = name_dd;
            }
        })
        let edit_form = '<div><div>' + response.some_data_from_rank + '</div>' +
            '<select>' + select_options + '</select>' +
            '</div>';

        $(".some_selector").html(edit_form);
    }
})
```

So, this doesn't work, by the time the first ajax finishes, the second one throws "undefined" where the dropdown is supposed to go. if in the second one I use `async:false` it works fine. Because the `async` is going to be deprecated, i wanted to know if there is another way of achieving the same thing keeping this structure (I already have other ways of doing it rewriting the whole thing and organising it different). Thanks!

Comment: just put second ajax in done or success, and get the data you want and update that in its success.  you probably dont need async.

Comment: if 1st response and 2nd follow up data are somehow related and derive from a database why not bring them in with a JOIN query together? Then you don't need a second ajax call at all

Comment: @AhmedSunny, i tried that, but in the first call, part of the html is built with the data and some of the html is built with the second one. the second call is supposed to return some values to buitl a dropdown in that html but always throws undefined. i guess i could put all the final parts of the build in the secon call so it will do the `$(".sosmclass").html(complete_html) ` only when the second call is complete, but then again, i'm curious to know how to do the `async:false` without using that (because it's deprecated).

Comment: @Vickel, that is another option, and it is in the alternatives i have. im not sure if i considered it already and for some reason i discard it but as i told @AhmedSunny, now i also want to know how to do it synchronised, that being `async:false` but without using that

Comment: you can share 2nd ajax, plus a simple html so that we can have more idea.  from your comment, you want to fill dropdown from 2nd ajax, i normally do like this, loading html with 1st ajax, and then load rest with ajax, like dynamic dropdowns, or datatables. you can create a function , which you can call in success, after doing .html(data)..

Comment: @AhmedSunny I think you are saying something similar to what I'm trying to do, but without seeing what you did is hard to tell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this. assign an id or selector to your newly created select
after loading your html from the first ajax, call the second ajax, and using the selector for select , append the options

the return does not work in success, the way it does in functions, you can use his way or a callback, but for your case, you can just use this simple way,

this way you dont need async:false, but if you want to return, meaning get the value from ajax and use it after it , then you need async:false for it.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: base_url + "/ranking/getranktoedit/" + rank_id,
    dataType: "json",
    sucess: function(response){
        let select_options;

        let edit_form = '<div><div>' + response.some_data_from_rank + '</div>' +
            '<select id="mySelect">' + select_options + '</select>' +
            '</div>';

        $(".some_selector").html(edit_form);// html is loaded now

        // second ajax to call dropdown content or whatever          
         $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url: base_url + "/getdropdown",
            data: {
                field:"name"
            },
            success: function(name_dd){
                $('#mySelect').val(name_dd); // this will select the option

            }
        })

    }
})
```

Comment: yeah bro, that worked perfect :) (sorry for the delay in my answer, due to the lockdown i spent most of my time away from the computer :P )

Comment: glad it helped,  you can also mark it as answer ..  stay safe. :)